# Disable the validation on field using netsuite api

Tags: netsuite

Can somebody help me to disable the validation on a mandatory field in netsuite field. I try to create a validation function but it doesn't work
  Thank you

Comment: Is that field is a standard one or custom field ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `customization > List, Records & Fields > Item fields`.
Edit that custom field and on the `Validation & Defaulting` tab you can `uncheck` the `mandatory` field and then just save. :)

Answer (score 0):

Various reasons why custom field is mandatory:
1. Custom field itself is mandatory in the 'Validation & Defaulting' subtab.
2. Custom field is not mandatory but made mandatory in the custom form
3. Custom field is made mandatory by a workflow or script

If the intention is not in general (i.e. making field non-mandatory for specific criteria), do a workflow instead of script. It's cleaner and easily editable by the users in case requirement changed.

Comment: But its possible to disable and enable the mandatory field in script? if yes how?